# How to fix connection problem with PostgreSQL

Tags: java, postgresql

It seams that IDEA tries to connect DB with local PC pid:

[image: picture]
But when I'm starting, there is:

```
2020-03-14 15:51:03.830  INFO 15541 --- [           main] com.project.ipsc.IpscApplication         : Starting IpscApplication on pc-X555LN with PID 15541 (/home/pc/ipsc/target/classes started by pc in /home/pc/ipsc)

org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: FATAL: password authentication failed for user "pc"
```

Comment: What does the PostgreSQL server log file tell you?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you try to connect to Postgresql it needs a user, so if you don't specify a real one it will take the default which is why you see "pc". 
Most likely you need to specify "postgres" as the user

Comment: Just used spring.datasource.username=root and everything Ok, previous annotation was wrong